# Live chart on 2nd window pop-up from 1st window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have window where I have a 'show and search' button. When I press the button, I want to show a live graph on a 2nd window (the show and search window), but I fail to plot the chart on it. Below is my code.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class controller():
    def __init__(self, container,model):
        self.container = container
        self.model=model()
        self.container.title('Jig run count')
        self.container.geometry('280x140')

    def set_up(self):
        self.add_remove_bt.place(x=10, y=50)
        self.count_search_bt = Button(self.container, text='   SHOW & SEARCH  ',
                                      command=self.show_and_search)
        self.count_search_bt.place(x=140, y=50) 

    def show_and_search(self):
        show_and_search_windows=Tk()
        show_and_search_form=Tk.winfo_toplevel(show_and_search_windows)
        show_and_search_form.title("jig status and search")
        show_and_search_form.geometry('800x500')
        self.graph_area=Frame(show_and_search_form,width=450, height=300).place(x=5,y=5)
        self.search_area=Frame(show_and_search_form,width=300, height=300).place(x=460,y=5)
        self.table_area=Frame(show_and_search_form,width=760, height=100).place(x=5,y=310)
        self.fig, self.ax1=plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.graph_area)
        ani=animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig,self.plot_chart,interval=1000)
        self.canvas_widget = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.canvas_widget.pack()

    def plot_chart(self):
        df=pd.read_csv(self.model.df_path,index_col='Type')
        FAT_df=df.loc['FAT'].sort_values(by="running_time",ascending=False)
        print(FAT_df)
        x1=FAT_df['jig_name'].values
        y1=FAT_df['running_time'].values
        print(x1)
        print(y1)
        self.ax1.clear()
        self.ax1.bar(x1,y1,label="top jigs")
        self.ax1.show()
```

Comment: Note that `self.graph_area`, `self.search_area` and `self.table_area` are all `None` because they are result of `.place(...)`.  So widgets created as children of them will be children of root window instead actually.  Also `show_and_search_form` is the same as `show_and_search_windows` actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `self.graph_area`, `self.search_area` and `self.table_area` are all `None` because they are result of `.place(...)`, so widgets created as children of them will be children of *root* window instead actually.

Also `show_and_search_form` is the same as `show_and_search_windows` actually.

Below is the modified `show_and_search()` to fix the above issues:

```py
class controller():
    ...

    def show_and_search(self):
        # better use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for child window
        show_and_search_form = Tk()
        show_and_search_form.title("jig status and search")
        show_and_search_form.geometry('800x500')
        # call .place(...) in separate line
        self.graph_area=Frame(show_and_search_form, width=450, height=300)
        self.graph_area.place(x=5, y=5)
        self.search_area=Frame(show_and_search_form, width=300, height=300, bg="cyan")
        self.search_area.place(x=460, y=5)
        self.table_area=Frame(show_and_search_form, width=750+5, height=100, bg="gold")
        self.table_area.place(x=5, y=310)
        self.fig, self.ax1 = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.graph_area)
        # used instance variable self.ani instead of local variable
        # to prevent garbage collection
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.plot_chart, interval=1000)
        self.canvas_widget = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
        self.canvas_widget.pack()

    ...
```

Comment: really appreciate your help and your advices in comments of the code.